# Device Directory

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, directory

So I have an app with dataBase. This database is in main bundle. But then I need to delete this database and get the new one from internet. As far as I understood, I can't delete anything from bundle and add new in it so I need to work with device documents directory. But I don't know how to make the first database to be in the documents directory without downloading it from internet. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get the path of documents directory and need to place your database file there. you need to do all read/write operations in your application from the copied database in your app's document directory.

I use these methods to create a copy of my DB in documents directory:
You just need to call this method:

> ```
> +(BOOL)copyDBFileToDocumentsDirectory:(NSString*)dbFilename overwrite:(BOOL)yesNO
> ```
>
> and just need to pass the filename with extension.

```
+(NSString*)databaseABSPath:(NSString*)databaseName existsInDocumentsDirectory:(BOOL)existenceStatus
{
    BOOL success = NO;

    NSString *databasePath = nil;

    if(existenceStatus)//documents Directory
    {
        NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    }
    else //from bundle
    {
        NSArray *resourceSeparatedByExtension = [databaseName componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

        if([resourceSeparatedByExtension count]<2)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with database name or extension");
            return nil;
        }

        databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[resourceSeparatedByExtension objectAtIndex:0] ofType:[resourceSeparatedByExtension objectAtIndex:1]];
    }

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Database file does not exist at path");
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        return databasePath;
    }


}

+(BOOL)copyDBFileToDocumentsDirectory:(NSString*)dbFilename overwrite:(BOOL)yesNO
{
    NSString *filePath = [mySQLiteDb databaseABSPath:dbFilename existsInDocumentsDirectory:NO];

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbFilename];

    if(filePath)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;

        if(!yesNO && [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath])
        {
            NSLog(@"File already exist at path - instruction is not to overwrite");
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:databasePath error:&error];
        }

        error = nil;

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:databasePath error:&error];

        if(!error)
            return YES;

        NSLog(@"Error copying file :\n\n%@\n\nuserinfo:%@\n\nFailure reason: %@\n\n",[error localizedDescription],[[error userInfo] description],[error localizedFailureReason]);
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: So this method copies DB from Bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the bundle by requesting path for a resource in the bundle. e.g.

```
NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self.imagesDict objectForKey:key] ofType:@"png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily path to document with this

```
NSString* pathToDocument = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
```

This will return a path to "Documents" folder, you have access to read & write data here